# flexbox container not always centering

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container (ul) that is intermittently centering (this is intended) and not (upon view refresh).  Is this a bug or is there something missing from the css?

[Live example on the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yzmqa57n/)

HTML:

```
<div id="lower-half">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href="catering.html">Catering</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: white;
}

nav ul li {
    align-self: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a weird issue - Is it browser-related? I just tried [pasting your code into a Pen](http://codepen.io/matiasvad/pen/MYoeJP?editors=110) and this does indeed center the nav.

However, to perhaps solve your issue, I've changed your CSS a bit, without it affecting your design and positioning - This may perhaps solve your refresh-issue.

[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/matiasvad/pen/qEjNmB?editors=110)

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
        </li> 
        <li>
            <a href="catering.html">Catering</a>
        </li> 
        <li>
            <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 360px;

    list-style: none;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}

nav ul li {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!  I need to study this a bit to understand the differences, but "bravo"!